# If div contains text, hide child ONLY in that div

Tags: jquery, hide

This should be so simple but I'm stuck.  I have a thumbnail page with several divs using the same classes, but unique text in each.

This is all I need:
1. If the div "foo" contains the unique text "Bad", then hide the "bar" div, but ONLY in THAT "container", not throughout the page.
2. If the div "foo" contains anything other than "Bad", do nothing.

This code works to find "Bad" and hide "foo"... but it hides it throughout the entire PAGE, not just within that specific "container."

```
<div class="container">
<div class="foo">Bad
<div class="bar">Heyo
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="foo">Not Bad
<div class="bar">Heyo
</div>
</div>
</div>



if ($('.foo:contains("Bad")').length > 0) {$( ".bar" ).hide()
```

Is this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":contains('Bad')")){
        $(this).children(".bar").hide();
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9t25d4f/20/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.foo:contains("bar")').each(function() {
  $(this).next('.bar').hide();
});
```

With [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) you go through each `.foo` separately. This allows you to address each matching `.bar`, something that `$('.bar')` does not. (If no matching `.foo` exists, the inner function is never called.)

[`.next('.bar')`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selects the next element, but only if it is a `.bar`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  This WOULD work, except "bar" wasn't actually the 'next' element in my code... I just simplified the code for this example.  There were a few other classes in between.  Thanks though!